# Tunning nginx/php5-fpm : why low memory usage with 800 users?

Tags: nginx, performance, php-fpm, performance-tuning

I did optimize nginx with what I found on the internet
My specs are **2 servers load balanced** :

- Intel Xeon E5-1620v2 (4c/8t 3,7 GHz+/3,9 GHz+)
- 32 Go DDR3 ECC 1600MHz
- 3x 160Go SSD Intel DC S3500 SATA3 6Gbps (raid 1)
- 1 Gbps

My optimisation for `nginx` are:

- `worker_processes 10;`
- `worker_rlimit_nofile 20000;`
- `keepalive_timeout 15;`
- `worker_connection 4096;`
- The rest of the optimizations [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/tristanbes/0a98edd237f125fbc9e1)

For php5-fpm (php 5.5.x):

- `pm_type: dynamic`
- `pm_max_children: 300`
- `pm_start_servers: 5`
- `pm_min_spare_servers: 5`
- `pm_max_spare_servers: 35`
- `pm_max_requests: 500`
- `pm_process_idle_timeout: 10s`

Others:

- Modify the maximum opened file for debian (`uopen`)
- Modify the maximum connection per socket

**The problem is, while on heavy load the 8CPU are 100%, the memory usage is very low (3Go used on 32Go available).**

The results of 800 users hitting the application for 1 minutes is available. Caution, keep in mind that there are 2 servers serving responses.

- http://screencast.com/t/vnpRRk12Ry8
- http://screencast.com/t/W126GJPYZH7

**Is there any other tuning options for `nginx` or `php-fpm` to allow better performances ? The low memory used kind of tells me i'm doing something wrong.**

Comment: I'd focus more on your database queries, indexes, and allocated memory than nginx/PHP here.

Comment: The database isn't on the web server, and it's a MariaDB server which does not show any trouble serving the 5k query per second (10% CPU) : http://screencast.com/t/h8kaCbWY8LKy . PS: I tuned MariaDB too

Comment: 5k queries looks like a lot of traffic. What does your network interfaces say?

Comment: Well, the web servers are communicating to the MariaDB server with another network card on a private network @ 1gbits seconds too. I serously doubt that this is the bottleneck. Maybe I reached the limit of tuning the nginx/php-fpm side ?

Comment: @Tristan That's pretty unlikely. How many PHP-FPM worker processes are actually running when things start bogging down. Are you seeing all 300 max_children?

Comment: I must admit i didn't count with htop :p. Nothing starts to "bug" it's just that the request takes 10 sec @ 600 users. Do I need to increase the max children ?